# wp_insert_post two values into the post_title

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working on inserting some data into my posts, I'm trying to insert two sets of data into the post title and I'm kinda stuck.

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => $data['title'],
```

This works fine, but I need to add another one to the title, how can I do that? for example

```
'post_title' => $data['title'] && $data['count'],
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dot `.` to concatenate the titles:

```
'post_title' => $data['title'] . $data['count'],
```

See the PHP docs on [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) for more info.